# old kernel removal since lts/hwe

Tags: 12.04, kernel

Since the move to 12.04 LTS/HWE, I now seem to have several linux kernel images stored.  I don't really care about the detail of what is going on here, but want to know which of the old kernels I can safely delete.  I can take a guess, but could someone please advise.
I include a screenshot of my existing set-up.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: At least some of those kernels can be removed using `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Autoremove did not signal removal of any of these images.

Comment: Just for completeness - purge of 3.8.0.44 automatically removes the associated generic-lts-raring image

Answer (score 1):

1. `uname -r`  - determine which kernel you are using at the moment.
2. `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` - to list all kernels
3. `apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic` - delete old unused kernel (just for example)
4. `sudo update-grub` - Now update grub so it knows that you don't have some of the kernels

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for technical how tos.  But that was not really the question. What I want to know is which kernels do I keep?  Just the one returned by the uname command?  What about the lts-raring and lts-trusty images?

Comment: It's up to you to decide which kernels to keep. I always use stable from kernel.org (3.17.1 at the time of writing), the last one from the series before (3.16.6), the latest longterm one (3.14.22) and the distro generic kernel.

Comment: So why do I have raring and trusty kernels?  You are asking me to make a decision I do not have the background to evaluate.

Comment: Just to clarify my concern/question.  Does the installed (uname -r) kernel contain all modules required, or is there any case where it may pull in modules from other kernels (such as raring or trusty), not specifically identified as installed?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i

NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')

ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"

METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"

UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $ADDKERNEL |grep -vE $METAKERNEL|grep -v $NEWKERNEL)

apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS

update-grub
```